# Como usar los datos de otra tabla como parametro de salida de un SELECT CASE - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito de alguna forma al realziar un select case que los datos despues del then sean obtenidos de otra tabla "master" por ejemplo, tengo este procedure donde dependiendo de la cantidad de eventos se le asigna un valor, quisiera que ese valor sea obtenido de otra tabla y proceder con la inserción del dato.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_TOTALES_INSERTAR`()
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE TOTALES;
    
    INSERT INTO TOTALES(ID_INSC_FK, ID_ACADEMIA_FK, NOMBRE_ATLETA, CEDULA_ATLETA, EVENTOS, MONTO_A_PAGAR) select tablota.*,
       case tablota.EVENTOS
        when 1 then 15000
        when 2 then 20000
        when 3 then 25000
        when 4 then 30000
       else 0 end as MONTO_A_PAGAR
from ( 
SELECT ID_INSCRIPCION, ID_ACA_FK, NOMBRE_ATLETA, CEDULA_ATLETA, COUNT(CEDULA_ATLETA) EVENTOS
FROM INSCRIPCIONES
GROUP BY CEDULA_ATLETA HAVING EVENTOS >= 1 ) as tablota;
END //
```

Es decir, los datos 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000 sean tomados de una tabla "MONTOS" por poner un ejemplo, pero no se cual es la mejor forma de hacerlo, si colocando variables o simplemente creando otro select a esa tabla.

Comment: No puedes cambiar el código mysql dinamicamente para hacer eso. Tendras que hacerlo programandolo; cargando todos los valores de la primera tabla y a continuacion  ir iterando por cada  valor. Aunque se pudiera (con una especie de eval), no te aconsejo esa aproximacion porque no seria lo suficientemente robusta: ¿Funcionaria con10.000 registros??? Posiblemente no

Comment: Lo que has hecho, es probablemente, lo más óptimo. Una sola select alimenta a todas las inserciónes....Al menos yo no veo el problema.

Comment: ¿Cómo se relacionan la cantidad de eventos con los montos? Agrega la estructura de las tablas. También algunos datos de ejemplo nos ayudarán a responderte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias opciones de lograrlo. Propongo una de las opciones, usar [`JOIN Clause`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) (disculpe, pero la documentación está en Inglés) y eliminar el `CASE`.

```sql
INSERT INTO `TOTALES` (
  `CEDULA_ATLETA`,
  `EVENTOS`,
  `MONTO_A_PAGAR`
)
SELECT
  `tablota`.`CEDULA_ATLETA`,
  `tablota`.`EVENTOS`,
  COALESCE(`MONTOS`.`MONTO_A_PAGAR`, 0) `MONTO_A_PAGAR`
FROM (
  SELECT
    `CEDULA_ATLETA`,
    COUNT(`CEDULA_ATLETA`) `EVENTOS`
  FROM
    `INSCRIPCIONES`
  GROUP BY
    `CEDULA_ATLETA`
) `tablota`
  LEFT JOIN `MONTOS` ON
    `tablota`.`EVENTOS` = `MONTOS`.`EVENTOS`;
```

Aquí un [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6O7gQxwH) con el ejemplo completo.

Comment: INSERT INTO TOTALES(ID_INSC_FK, ID_ACADEMIA_FK, NOMBRE_ATLETA, CEDULA_ATLETA, EVENTOS, MONTO_A_PAGAR)
SELECT
  `tablota`.`CEDULA_ATLETA`,
  `tablota`.`EVENTOS`,
  COALESCE(`MONTOS`.`MONTO_A_PAGAR`, 0) `MONTO_A_PAGAR`
FROM (
  SELECT
    ID_INSCRIPCION, ID_ACA_FK, NOMBRE_ATLETA, CEDULA_ATLETA, COUNT(CEDULA_ATLETA) EVENTOS
  FROM
    `INSCRIPCIONES`
  GROUP BY
    `CEDULA_ATLETA`
) `tablota`
  LEFT JOIN `MONTOS` ON
    `tablota`.`EVENTOS` = `MONTOS`.`EVENTOS`;

Comment: Así es como lo he hecho pero me da el siguiente error

Comment: 0 70 19:16:54 INSERT INTO TOTALES(ID_INSC_FK, ID_ACADEMIA_FK, NOMBRE_ATLETA, CEDULA_ATLETA, EVENTOS, MONTO_A_PAGAR)
 SELECT
   `tablota`.`CEDULA_ATLETA`,
   `tablota`.`EVENTOS`,
   COALESCE(`MONTOS`.`MONTO_A_PAGAR`, 0) `MONTO_A_PAGAR`
 FROM (
   SELECT
     ID_INSCRIPCION, ID_ACA_FK, NOMBRE_ATLETA, CEDULA_ATLETA, COUNT(CEDULA_ATLETA) EVENTOS
   FROM
     `INSCRIPCIONES`
   GROUP BY
     `CEDULA_ATLETA`
 ) `tablota`
   LEFT JOIN `MONTOS` ON
     `tablota`.`EVENTOS` = `MONTOS`.`EVENTOS` Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 0.093 sec